# How to do use precompiled headers with gcc and make?

Tags: gcc, dependencies, makefile, precompiled-headers

I have a make file that uses the -MMD -MP options when invoking g++.  This creates the .d dependency files that look something like this:

```
blah.o: header1.h header2.h
```

Now, I'm trying to add precompiled header support, and would like to have a rule similar to:

```
$(OUT_DIR)/%.h.pch: $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

and then I'd like the .d files to look like this:

```
blah.o: header1.h.pch header2.h.pch
```

That way the .o files are dependent on the precompiled headers, and the precompiled headers depend on the headers.  That way I can be sure that any precompiled headers are created BEFORE the dependent .cpp file is compiled.  My problem is I can't figure out a way to have g++ create dependency files that have the *.pch extensions.  Everything I try always produces the typical .h extensions.  Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

How about adding a command

```
sed -e 's/.h /.h.pch /g' -e 's/.h$/.h.pch/' $*.d > $*.dd
```

(You can modify `foo.d` in place if you prefer.)

Comment: I, in fact, did this as a "temporary solution".  However, it may end up being a more permanent solution.